# AWS CloudWatch dashboard CloudFormation configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to confgure a dashboard with a basic widget to expose CpUUtilization metric.
I cannot reference the previous created EC2 instance, since it seems that in the json that describe the dashboard the !Ref function is not interpreted.

```
metrics": [
        "AWS/EC2",
        "CPUUtilization",
        "InstanceId",
        "!Ref Ec2Instance"
]
```

Any idea how to reference it by logical name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Fn::Join` to combine the output of Intrinsic functions (like `Ref`) with strings. For example:

```
  CloudWatchDashboardHOSTNAME:
    Type: "AWS::CloudWatch::Dashboard"
    DependsOn: Ec2InstanceHOSTNAME
    Properties:
      DashboardName: HOSTNAME
      DashboardBody: { "Fn::Join": [ "", ['{"widgets":[
          {
            "type":"metric",
            "properties":{
              "metrics":[
                ["AWS/EC2","CPUUtilization","InstanceId",
                 "', { Ref: Ec2InstanceHOSTNAME }, '"] 
              ],
              "title":"CPU Utilization",
              "period":60,
              "region":"us-east-1"
            }
          }]}' ] ] }
```

Documentation:

- [Fn::Join - AWS CloudFormation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-join.html)
- [Ref - AWS CloudFormation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-ref.html)
- [AWS::CloudWatch::Dashboard - AWS CloudFormation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cw-dashboard.html)
- [Dashboard Body Structure and Syntax - Amazon CloudWatch](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/CloudWatch-Dashboard-Body-Structure.html)